# DataGridViewLinkCell event crash desktop app

Tags: c#

I tried to make simple CRUD desktop app with Visual Studio C# following some tutorials.

I have connected a small SQL Server and everything ok until I've implemented 2 link buttons to edit and erase. Now every time I click on any other cell that comes with the query, app crash.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace URL_API_v2
{
    public partial class MLA_URL : Form
    {
        private CN_MLA _CN_MLA;
        public MLA_URL()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _CN_MLA = new CN_MLA();
        }
        #region EVENTOS
        private void btnAgregar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenMLAadd();
        }
        #endregion

        #region Metodos Privados
        private void OpenMLAadd()
        {
            AgregarMLA agregarMLA = new AgregarMLA();
            agregarMLA.ShowDialog(this);
        }
        #endregion

        private void MLA_URL_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Populate();
        }
        public void Populate(string Buscar = null)
        {
            List<tablaMLA> consulta = _CN_MLA.GetMLAs(Buscar);
            MLA.DataSource = consulta;
        }

        private void MLA_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridViewLinkCell cell = (DataGridViewLinkCell)MLA.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
            if (cell.Value.ToString() == "EDITAR")
            {
                AgregarMLA agregarMLA = new AgregarMLA();
                agregarMLA.LoadContact(new tablaMLA
                {

                    URL_ID = int.Parse(MLA.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString()),
                    URL_QUERY = (MLA.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1]).Value.ToString()
                });
                agregarMLA.ShowDialog(this);
            }
            else if (cell.Value.ToString() == "BORRAR")
            {

                BorrarMLA(int.Parse(MLA.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString()));
                Populate();
            }
        }
        private void BorrarMLA (int URL_ID)
        {
            _CN_MLA.BorrarMLA(URL_ID);
        }

        private void btnBuscar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Populate(txtSearch.Text);
            txtSearch.Text= string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone have a look? Basically this Main outputs a DataGrid with a basic "select * from table1" with 2 additional (not linked columns) with a the text "edit" and "erase" so you can click on them and do that. BUT, wherever you click on another random cell, error comes up with something like:

> `Cannot convert DataGridViewLinkCell to DataGridViewTextBox`

and if you debug first line in the "MLA_CellContentClick" is highlighted.

Comment: Oh!! Im sorry!! My complete mistake. There it goes. This is code for the main code that it's actually crashing:

Comment: When you run the app it brings a tipicall "selct * from table1" and you have 2 columns extra (not part of the SQL statement) that are meant to "edit" and "erase". But wherever you click on another cell, error comes up with something like "Cannot connvert DataGridViewLinkCell to DataGridViewTextBox and if you debug first line in the "MLA_CellContentClick" is highlited. Sorry im not that expert to tell you more than that...

Comment: Hi Dale! Thanks for your answer. Sorry to ask you this, but where should I put this? Before the other If ? Column index should be the ones without link text isn't it? And after return, what?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your error was the other way around, which I suspect it must be, then first test whether the cell is of the type you are trying to cast it to, and if not just return without further processing.

```
private void MLA_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if !(MLA.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewLinkCell) return;

    var cell = MLA.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex] as DataGridViewLinkCell;

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Boom! Total Magic. Thats and awesome solution. Dale, thanks a lot!! Really i was totally blocked with this. Again...Thanks